# Firebase functions extremely slow network when uploading files to storage. ECONNRESET error

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have a Nodejs 18 http firbase function gen 2.
The context  of this project is an AI project where users send a request to this function that generates images using SDXL.

For this example, we are sending a request to an external REST API that uses the SDXL and responds with a base64 image. That image is then uploaded to Firebase storage using the storage JS package. The issue here is that running this locally takes about 20 seconds, whereas once deployed it takes 3 minutes.

Generating the images and receiving the base64 response takes quite a while and about 5 times as long as it would running this locally with `firbase serve`. To exclude the thrid parties response time we can focus on uploading the image once the base64 string has been received. The image generation and upload are run together async normally in batching of three. See the below code and the time it took to save the image.

```
console.log("IMAGE GENERATED");
await saveImageFromBase64(res.data.output.choices[0].image_base64, imagePath);
console.log("IMAGE SAVED");
```

```
const saveImageFromBase64 = async (base64: string, path: string) => {
  try {
    const bucket = storage.bucket("gs://acbxyz.appspot.com");
    const file = bucket.file(path);
    const bf = Buffer.from(base64, "base64");
    await file.save(bf, {
      contentType: "image/png",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error uploading image:", error);
  }
};
```

Batch of three

[image]

Single upload

[image]

Each image is normally only around 1.8mb. Not sure why it is taking so almost 30 seconds to upload three images of 1.8mb each and almost 14 seconds to upload a single image of 1.8mb. Serving the function locally takes a 10th of the time as it does when deployed. In the deployed function it sometimes takes so long to upload the image that axios throws a ECONNRESET error.

Is this expected speed? If so how can I increase it? Am I missing something or doing something wrong here? I have made sure that its all running in the same region in the US. When it runs faster locally with firebase serve, I am in australia. So it's not a location issue.

Things I have tried that didn't help:

1. Increasing the memory and cpu of the function. Set it to 4gb and 2 cpu.
2. Running all network traffic through a vpc-connector.

EDIT: the issue was that I was sending a request back to the user, early on in the function `res.status(200).json({progressId: docId})`.  Because the function normally can take up to a minute, this was so that the user can run a listener on the progress document and see the progress of the content being created as the function continues to create the content in the background, updating the progress document.

Is there a way to avoid this throttling behavior after sending a response back to the user early on in the function?

Comment: Please edit the question to show the entire function code that doesn't work the way you expect, along with your debugging details.

Comment: A deployed cloud function is [severely throttled or even killed](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) when the function **thinks** it has completed. As Doug covered above, we need the rest of your Cloud function to find out if you have managed the Cloud Function lifecycle properly.

Comment: @samthecodingman Your comment helped me locate the issue. What I was doing was sending a request back to the user very early on in the function "res.status(200).json({progressId: docId})". Because the function normally can take up to a minute, this was so that the user can run a listener on the progress document and see the progress in a progress bar of the content being created as the function continues to create the content in the background, updating the progress document. Is the a way to bypass this behaviour? I'll update the question. Thank you!

Comment: @TheAce To my knowledge, this behaviour cannot be disabled. As an alternative, you could use your Cloud Function to create a Firestore document with the validated request data, then return the path of that document to the caller. Using a Firestore `onCreate` document trigger, you would make each image generation request and update that same (or another) document on completion.